# error in sql lite for windows store apps Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3':

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

i have an error when run the application error in sql lite functions 
this is a picture for the error

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/ggby.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried sqlite with winstore using this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263243.aspx ) article and it works for me.